# Obtener Texto Por Medio de Un InputDialog en Java

Tags: java, sql-server, base-de-datos, get

Tengo un InputDialog y el dato ingresado mandarlo a SQL Server pero no me sale ya que no puedo obtener el valor por medio de un getText().
Adjunto mi codigo

```
 String Agregar = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa Nombre del Departamento", "Nuevo Departamento", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icono, null, null);
    
    if (Agregar.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "!! No Has Ingresado un Departamento !!");
        
    }else{
        try {
            pstm = ConexionSQL.Conexion.conn.prepareCall("INSERT INTO Departamentos (Departamento) VALUES(?)");
            String get = Agregar;
            pstm.setString(1, get.getText());
            
            int Ejecucion = pstm.executeUpdate();
            
            if (Ejecucion>0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "!! Registro Exitoso !!");
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha Presentado el siguiente error " + ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Departamento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estas intentando aplicar el método getText() de JTextComponent cuando no deberías, ya que se lo estas intentando aplicar a un String (get):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El JInputDialog te devuelve ya de por si un String, que lo estas almacenando en Agregar:

```
 String Agregar = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingresa Nombre del Departamento", "Nuevo Departamento", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icono, null, null);
    
    if (Agregar.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "!! No Has Ingresado un Departamento !!");
        
    }else{
        try {
            pstm = ConexionSQL.Conexion.conn.prepareCall("INSERT INTO Departamentos (Departamento) VALUES(?)");
            
            pstm.setString(1, Agregar);
            
            int Ejecucion = pstm.executeUpdate();
            
            if (Ejecucion>0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "!! Registro Exitoso !!");
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha Presentado el siguiente error " + ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Departamento.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Si no es este el error comentamelo :D

Comment: Hola amigo, no puede resolver el problema ya que con colocar la variable Agregar no me lee lo que ingrese ya que falta el tipo getText(), pero la variable Agregar no es de tipo JTextField.

Comment: Algo no estoy entendiendo del todo. El método getText de JTextComponent te devuelve un String. Pero tu ya tienes un String llamado Agregar donde tienes almacenado el texto introducido en en el InputDialog.... Como te digo, poniendo Agregar.getText() no debería ni compilarte, ya que ese método (getText()) no pertenece a la clase String, que es a donde quieres aplicarlo. Cuál es exactamente el problema que tienes? O sea, despues de hacer esos dos pequeños cambios que te pronpongo-

Comment: cree una variable de tipo JTextField la cual la iguale a la variable Agregar, despues declare que JTextField.setText(Agregar);

Comment: Pero lamentablemente en pstm.setString(0,JtextField.getText()); me vota error en el siguiente codigo________JTextField.setText(Agregar);